# Unwanted horizontal padding in Safari & Chrome between images inside div

Tags: safari, padding

I am trying to display 3 images across the width of a div with no margin or padding between them. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari whereupon these 2 browsers put padding in between the images and thus push the third image below the first two.

The container the div is in is 650 pixels wide. The images are 217, 217 and 216 pixels wide. I have tried css to set the horizontal margins and padding to 0 both in the div and in the individual images but it doesn't work. I tried shaving off a few pixels off one image but it didn't work either. I also tried setting the display to inline. The only workable solution I have is to combine the 3 images into 1 whereupon the total 650 pixel width of the image sits within the div ok. All 3 browsers are current versions.

```
<div class="wrap mb16">
    <div class="main column">
        <div class="mb06"">
            <img src="images/method-1.jpg">
            <img src="images/method-2.jpg">
            <img src="images/method-3.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrap { 
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    }
.main { 
    width: 650px;
    background: #FCFCFC;
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-right: 75px;
}
.column { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.mb06 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
}
.mb16 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
}
```

I was expecting Firefox, Chrome and Safari to behave the same and display all 3 images in a row without any padding in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use flexbox styles? I'm on a Chrome browser and I'm seeing the images lined edge to edge with:

```
.mb06 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
    /* Flex styling */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; // optional to center the three images together in this wrapper
}
```

You can read about the other options it offers here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for drawing my attention to 'flex', it works perfectly. Cheers.